# .DLL error when installing firmware for Dell PE2900 PERC 5/i RAID

Tags: raid, windows-server-2000, dll, firmware

I'm installing a new RAID firmware version (2.5.0) for a Dell PE2900 which has a PERC 5/i RAID setup. When I run the installer, it gives the message "The procedure entry point RegDeleteKeyExA could not be located in the dynamic link library ADVAPI32.dll." It seems as though the installer wants to delete a registry key but can't find the .dll function that allows it to do so. I've verified that the .dll does exist. My ultimate fear is that Windows Server 2000 does not have the function that allows the installer to run. Has anyone had this experience before? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out. The NTFS security properties of the .dll being referenced had been set without write permission. When the function that attempts to write to the registry is accessed, the program has a permissions error and fails.